# Need help troubleshooting vi + cygwin issue

Tags: vim, cygwin, terminal

I've just added `vim` to my current Cygwin installation, and it doesn't work properly.

The problem is: when I type `vim <Enter>` it opens Vim with the help splash screen (in color) - OK.

I then try to exit with `:q` , and it sleeps a couple of seconds, then it exits but when I type a character at the command line it pre-pends a spurious string (`6c6c`). Other similar issues when I try to edit a file in vi instead of exiting right away.

I suppose it is a color/TERM issue, but I don't have much experience in that kind of stuff.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What OS version? Have you tried doing a fresh install of cygwin+vim somewhere to see if it has the same issue?

Comment: OS version: xp professional 2002 SP2.
Actually, I used to work with the same setup till last year, and it worked.

Comment: I can't really say what's going on here, as I've never had any such thing happen with Cygwin, but you might want to consider just downloading the "regular" Win32 build from the Vim homepage and using that instead of the Cygwin build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What terminal are you launching vim from?  [I'd suggest using rxvt](http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Rxvt).  This solves many issues with ncurses type programs.

Sometimes people change their TERM variable.  Generally, you shouldn't do this, so long as your environment has the correct termcap installed, this isn't needed.  If your use rvxt your TERM variable will default to 'rxvt-cygwin-native'.